# How to fix pie charts size in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, properties, size, pie-chart

I have 4 charts created in SSRS 2017 and I need them to be the same size.
Are there any settings (and where? in SSRS) to make size all the same for all of my 4 charts?

When I go into Chart Area properties, there is nothing about the chart size...

Please help!

[image]

Update:
When I clicking on the Chart Area slightly outside the actual chart I see the following Chart Properties:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, while you can set the size of the chart element, the size of the pie will change due to the changing Legend that you have. The other option would be to make your own legend but then you'd need to assign the colors to the data rather than use the color scheme. Maybe try duplicating each chart and hide the Pie in one and the remove the legend from the other? Since they're in the same order, the colors should match.

Comment: Thank you, @Hannover Fist...,
- I tried coping charts, but since I have multiple datasets for each of the pie chart - it only showed the dataset assigned to my 1st pie.
And if I create a new chart - it shows all datasets (which what I needed)
Is there any way to show all datasets to a copied chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the position of the chart area and the plot position of the pie within the area by setting the CustomPosition and CustomInnerPlotPosition properties. Select the chart area first to see these properties.

**Please note: You must select the CHART AREA object in the designer not the chart** Just click slightly outside the pie to select the correct area then you will see these properties.

[image]

You can do the same for the legend too if required so you can get full control over the final rendered size.

It does take a bit of trial and error to get a layout that suits all your needs but it can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no CustomPosition or CustomInnerPlotPosition when selecting the chart area...
Could it be because of the different SSRS version(s)?

I was able to resolve my problem by adjusting the legend size...

Comment: What are you using of edit the reports? Visual Studio , Report Builder? And which version. I'll 99% certain this is available in every editor. Let me know and I'll update with screen shots. It might help you in the future.

Comment: I am using Ms Visual Studio Professional 2017...
I was not able to find CustomPosition or CustomInnerPlotPosition ...
I think, I can modify my original post to screenshot what appears in my 
Chart Area
Otherwise - Thank you very much for all the efforts... !!!

Comment: Just added one more picture in the original post

Comment: You need to use the properties panel, not the limited properties window you are looking at. If using visual studio, click the chart area and press F4. If you are using Report Builder, click the view tab and switch `properties` on.  You'll find a ton of useful stuff in these properties that you just can't do in the pretty GUI version.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. That properties panel is what I use the most, it offers lots of options that are just not visible in the other view.

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly influence the size of the chart, like `Hannover Fist` said it depends on multiple conditions (for example the legend). What you can do is to put the legend on top or on bottom of the chart (the reason for the different sizes of your charts it that the legend text from right to left is different, thus it uses the space from the visual). This way the size of the chart should be more or less the same size. Right click on your legend **Legend properties > General > Legend position**. With the **MaxAutoSize** property from the legend you can a little bit control the size of your legend.

To your second question. No, a chart (also tablix and matrix) can only have one Dataset as source. You can see this in the chart properties at the drop down list. You just can chose one element. But you can create one big dataset with all the data for the different charts. Then assign this dataset to one chart and copy it. And then you set different filters to the charts.

Comment: Thank you for all the info
I was able to make my pie charts about the same size by shortening the legend values - making them about the same size for each "pie"

Also, there is a possibility to change the dataset in case if needed to copy an existing pie chart (since I have multiple datasets - different for each pie chart) -  by coping chart, clicking on the chart area - Chart\ Chart Properties \ Dataset Name, select a specific dataset you need

Comment: Yes thats the way I do it too, to control the chart sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above didn't help.  The varying sizes of pie charts related to the fact that some had been set to have their series value > label > position = outside and others were position = auto.  All pie charts had their labels hidden so you coudln't see them at all but SSRS was allowing space for them when set to position = outside.  This made it extremely frustrating to chase down where the difference in size was coming from.  Hope this may help someone who comes across a similar issue.